# PHP/jQuery to submit/save input with all special characters value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, character

Example..

**HTML :**

```
<input type="hidden" value="">
```

**PHP :**

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $value;?>">
```

**jQuery :**

```
$("input:hidden").val(text);
```

If `text`*(JS variable)* is free text, All html special characters allowed (like single quote / double quote) and save to `input:hidden` (so submit by PHP)

What is a correctly way to do ?

May I use

`echo htmlentities($value);` ... in PHP

or replace quotes in jQuery like `.val(text.replace(/'/g,"’"))`

or what ?

PS : Please think about when I set value to input to save value with jQuery too.

Comment: Is there any jquery function .value()? I hope it is available in JAVASCRIPT

Comment: sorry `.val()`@EdwinAlex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting to [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) should work fine.

You can also use [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) if you want to remove all HTML tags :

**Note:** this will NOT stop all XSS attacks

Comment: What about set value back to HTML by jquery ?

Comment: Note 100% sure, but when you use html entities you don't actually use a "quote" etc. So the html entities might be allowed already and rendered correctly. Also, even though it might not be needed in your specific case, I always json encode on the PHP side and decode the value again och the javascript side before using it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to echo a PHP variable into some HTML, use:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($value); ?>">
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

If you want to echo a PHP variable into some JavaScript, use:

```
<?php echo json_encode($value); ?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: I just only have to use `htmlspecialchars()` by PHP ? so everthing will work ? What about when I put value to input with jQuery ?